# start , stop, restart apache using vb6

Tags: apache, vb6

I am developing an application in vb6 that will need to start , stop, restart Apache. 
how do i do this? 
if Apache is installed as a service, how do i detect it and still carry out the former action on it?

Comment: *(Devil's advocate)* what if there are multiple instances of Apache running, e.g. one normal one and one wrapped in a VisualSVN instance? Would you start with a port number?

Comment: on starting, my app makes the use choose a specified Apache folder to work with. i don't imagine a user running more that one instance of Apache for any reason, but if otherwise, pls advise me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the standard windows commands for manipulating a service:

```
net start apache
net stop apache
```

So, in VB6, you'd issue the following:

```
shell("net start apache")
shell("net stop apache")
```

If you are in the Active Directory environment, you could you [those objects to manipulate services](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/19288).

As far as detecting whether Apache is installed as a service, I'd [enumerate through the installed services](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/network/enumservicesadv.htm) and see if Apache is in the list.

Comment: this will only work if the application is running as a service. am talking about finding the Apache path, and the apache executable and starting Apache